# change a particular column value using awk / sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with 52 columns. I want to replace 11th column from 0 to 1. All the data in my file are "|" separated. I tried the below command.

```
awk -F \| '{$11=1; print}' input_file.txt
```

I have got the 11th column replaced with above command. But the output of this file changed the separator to "space". I cannot just remove space from outfile, because few columns have valid spaces as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`OFS` (output field seperator)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html) to be the same as your `FS` (Field Seperator which is set with your `-F` flag) in the `BEGIN` clause of your `awk` script otherwise it's set to the default of `" "`

```
awk -F \| 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$11=1; print}' input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -re 's/(^\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|)([^|]*)\|(.*)/\11|\3/'
```

Filter your file through this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this sed:

```
sed -E 's/(([^|]*\|){10})[^|]*(.*)/\11\3/' infile
```

If you want only change from 0 to 1

```
sed -E 's/(([^|]*\|){10})0(.*)/\11\3/' infile
```